# Transferir valor de data de Form1 para classe c# windows form .net

Tags: c#, sql, .net, windows

Estou trabalhando com o windows form .net c# mas não tenho muita prática e gostaria de uma ajuda...

Tenho um componente calendario em um form1  e apos rodar a aplicacao, é selecionado uma data a qual fica armazenada em uma var.Até ai tudo bem. Criei uma classe como mostra abaixo:
Nesta Classe preciso receber o valor da data escolhida no form1  e não sei como fazer...

Form1

```
private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (validaPeriodo() == true)
    {
        btnValidar.Enabled = true;
        btnGerar.Enabled = false;
        btnVisualizarFalha.Enabled = false;

        NewDb openDb = new NewDb();
        DataTable resultado = new DataTable();

        using (MySqlConnection db = openDb.AbrirConexaoMySql())
        {
            try
            {
                db.Open();


                if (CESDI.SelectedTab.Text == "CESDI")
                {
                    MySqlCommand sqlCommand = MamData.MySql.CESDI.SelectCESDI(db, dtaDataInicio.Text, dtaDataFinal.Text);
                    txtNAtos.Text = MamData.MySql.CESDI.SelectAtosCesdi(db, dtaDataInicio.Text, dtaDataFinal.Text);
                    inicializarGrids(sqlCommand, gridCESDI);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Classe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using MamData;
using System.Net;
using Comunicacao.Dal;

using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace Comunicacao.XML.CENSEC
{
    public class GeraSEFAZ
    {
        public static string dataInicial;
        public static string dataFinal;

        static public string geraXmlSEFAZ(List<DataGridViewRow> registros)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, melhora a sua pergunta, ela ficou mal formata em relação ao código e também o código está incompleto e meio confuso.

Answer (score 1):

Para usar data você terá de trabalhar com `DateTime`. Não vejo como trabalhar a data no seu código só com String.

Por exemplo:

```
DateTime dataInicio = DateTime.Now; //Usando a data atual
```